# event clicks called once every two

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

For beginning, sorry for my english (I'm french).

I created a customNumericUpDown with a TableLayoutPanel of 3 columns and 1 row. The first cell contains the textbox, the second contains a button to decrease value and the third contains a button to increase value.

The custom numericUpDown works correctly but I have a little problem when I click on the buttons: the click event is calling one every two. I also use the mousedown and mouseup event to increase or decrease the value automatically.

```
private void mawSkinUltimateButtonDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Increase = false;
     value -= increment;
     if (value >= maximum)
     {
        value = maximum;
     }
     if (value <= minimum)
     {
        value = minimum;
     }
     textBoxNumeric.Text = value.ToString();
     if (ValueChanged != null)
     {
        ValueChanged(sender, e);
     }
}

private void mawSkinUltimateButtonUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Increase = true;
     value += increment;
     if (value >= maximum)
     {
        value = maximum;
     }
     if (value <= minimum)
     {
        value = minimum;
     }
     textBoxNumeric.Text = value.ToString();
     if (ValueChanged != null)
     {
         ValueChanged(sender, e);
     }
  }

private void mawSkinUltimateButtonDown_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
       Increase = false;
       mawSkinUltimateButtonDown.Focus();
       dec = false;
       value = double.Parse(textBoxNumeric.Text);
       timer.Start();
}

private void mawSkinUltimateButtonDown_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
       timer.Interval = 400;
       timer.Stop();
       Increase = false;
       dec = false;
       i = 0;
       if (value >= maximum)
       {
          value = maximum;
       }
       if (value <= minimum)
       {
          value = minimum;
       }
       if (ValueChanged != null)
       {
          ValueChanged(sender, e);
       }
}

private void mawSkinUltimateButtonUp_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
      Increase = true;
      mawSkinUltimateButtonUp.Focus();
      dec = true;
      value = double.Parse(textBoxNumeric.Text);
      timer.Start();
}

private void mawSkinUltimateButtonUp_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     timer.Interval = 400;
     timer.Stop();
     Increase = false;
     dec = false;
     i = 0;
     if (value >= maximum)
     {
         value = maximum;
     }
     if (value <= minimum)
     {
         value = minimum;
     }
     if (ValueChanged != null)
     {
         ValueChanged(sender, e);
     }
}
```

I think the problem could be the mousedown event because I learnt it is raised before the click event but I don't know how call click event first.

Comment: What happens when you click on the button, keep the mouse button clicked, move the mouse outside the button and then release the mouse button? Why do you need to handle the up/down events?

Comment: Why do you think the click event is being called twice (is that what "one every two" means)?  What is the timer code doing?

Comment: When I quickly click on the button it is clicked once on two (a classic numericUpDown does not have this behavior)

Comment: The timer is here to increase or decrease the value of the textbox when I stay clicked

Comment: So you increase it on a click, and on a timer start.  Wouldn't that be your "two increases"?

Comment: I found this code on the internet to create a customNumericUpDown. I see this docs https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/framework/winforms/mouse-events-in-windows-forms about the mousedown event calling first

Comment: The sequence of events is `Mouse Down`, `Click`, `Mouse Click`, `Mouse Up` if the mouse button is released inside the Button's bounds. `Mouse Down`, `Mouse Up` if released outside. The `Click` event is not that useful. Make a first-chance increment/decrement in `MouseDown`. You should move you Min/Max evaluations to a single method (to DRY your code a bit)

Comment: If I delete the Click event, the value doesn't change.